# Client Server File Transfer

Tags: java, java-io

Hi I am having a problem while transferring my files from client to server side. From my initial research, I found DataInputStream which can be used for my transfer. But unfortunately, the files which are transfered using DataInput/Output Stream gets corrupted. The file size remains the same but when i open the files , I don't see content and the text show hex content in it.
From some of the internet links, I found that it might be due to open sockets or streams but that didn't work out well enough. Can anyone please help me on this problem. My file gets corrupted after each transfer.

Below is my code:

```
Client Side Code
if (isConnected) {
        File transferFile = new File(dir);
        if (!transferFile.exists() || !transferFile.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("error");
            System.err.println();
        }
        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();           
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) transferFile.length()];
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeUTF(transferFile.getName());
        dos.writeLong(bytearray.length);
        dos.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
        os.close();

Server Side Code
    /* Test Code */
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(is);
        String fileName =in.readUTF();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        long size = in.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1)
        {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }
        is.close();
        output.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();

Content of Input File: 
This is a test file.

Contents of Output File:(Received by Server)
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000
```

Comment: Add a small file before and after upload so we can see the error.

Comment: sure lemme do it right away

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something *completely* obvious, but where is `bytearray` given meaningful data?  It appears you are writing an array full of zero-valued bytes.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length().
Returns:
The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes.

Your approach is wrong! If the file is too big lets say it is 2GB+ you can get OutOfMemoryError because the maximum number of elements in array is Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8 if I am not mistaken. what will happen if 100 files are read in same time ? my suggestion is to use byte[127000] or even 8000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never actually writing the file across.  You are only writing a zero-valued byte array (your `bytearray` variable) that has the same size as the file.  The server receives the byte array, full of zero-valued bytes, and saves it to a file.  The server's saved file therefore has the same size as the original file, but is full of zeros (NULLs), which will appear as garbage in most text editors.  You need to actually write the file contents into `bytearray` first.